# Can I publish a paper while being employed by a scientific publishing house?

Tags: publications, conflict-of-interest

I have got a job offer from Springer Nature as associate scientific editor. I am joining the company next month. Currently I am a postdoc researcher at a university. I have a couple of papers from postdoc that will be completed over the course of the next year.

Given that I will be in the employment of the publishing house during next year, will it be ethical to submit my paper to a journal associated with Springer?

Comment: As long you are not the handling editor, I don't see it as a problem.  Your situation is the same as the editors of any journals.

Answer (score 3):

Ethically yes, as long as you don't have any influence over the decisions necessary to publish it. This can normally be arranged by a journal. This avoids any *actual* conflict.

But, practically, it will depend on the rules established by the employer. I suspect that most will not want to rule it out, entirely. They will likely establish rules to avoid not only conflict of interest, but the *appearance* of conflict of interest.

So, in the specific case, ask Springer.